# Background choices that allows static gauge in string theory

Tags: general-relativity, spacetime, string-theory, coordinate-systems, gauge-theory

Consider the Polyakov action after fixing the conformal gauge $h_{ab}=\eta_{ab}$:

$$S_P[X] = -\frac{T}{2} \int \text{d}^2 \sigma \eta^{ab} \partial_a X^\mu \partial_b X^\nu G_{\mu \nu} (X) \tag1$$
where $G_{\mu \nu}$ are the metric components of the ambient space, i.e. the background.
Even after fixing the gauge of the worldsheet metric, this action still have a symmetry left. In fact, for an infinitesimal Weyl transformation such that $$\delta_{\phi} h^{ab} = \phi(\sigma) \eta^{ab},\  \phi >0$$ ,
we can make an infinitesimal reparametrization in the worldsheet

$$\sigma^a \longrightarrow \sigma^a + \xi^a(\sigma) \tag2$$

we have also that

$$\delta_{\xi} h ^{ab} = -\partial^a \xi^b - \partial^b \xi^a \tag3$$

where $\partial^a = \eta^{ab} \partial_b$.

If we restrict the reparametrizations such that

$$ \partial^a \xi^b + \partial^b \xi^a = \phi \eta^{ab} $$
our reparametrization will cancels out the weyl transformations. These diffeomorphism are the well known conformal transformations.

As discussed in Becker & Becker, Schwarz String Theory textbook, section 2.5, it is discussed that, using $\xi^\pm = \xi ^0 \pm \xi^1 $ $\sigma^{\pm} = \sigma^0 \pm \sigma^1$, the allowed transformations are those in which $\sigma^\pm \longrightarrow \sigma'^\pm (\sigma^\pm)$. In fact, by definition of lightcone coordinates, $\tau = \frac{1}{2} (\sigma^+ + \sigma^-)$, and so

$$\tau \longrightarrow \tau^\prime =\frac{1}{2} (\sigma'^+ + \sigma'^-) \tag4$$

which is a solution of a free wave equation

$$(\partial^2_\sigma - \partial^2_\tau) \tau'=0 $$

We have also equations of motion for the embedding coordinates $X^\mu$:

$$\eta^{ab} (\partial_a \partial_b X^\mu + \Gamma^\mu _{\nu \rho} \partial_a X^\nu \partial_b X^\rho)=0$$

If we are able to make the second term inside brackets vanish, then the coordinates $X^\mu$ will also satisfy a free wave equation, and then, we can use the residual symmetry to fix the coordinates in term if the parameter $\tau$. The one that I'm interested is the Static Gauge: $X^0(\tau, \sigma) = \kappa \tau, \kappa \in \mathbb{R}_{>0}$.

**MY PROBLEM**: My advisor asked me to find in which classes of backgrounds the static gauge choice is possible. The simplests spacetimes that allows static gauge are the flat ones, bevause we can always find a coordinate system in ambient space such that the $\Gamma$s vanish. However, I can't go further on it. I have already tried for static spacetimes for which $\Gamma^0_{\mu \nu}$ could vanish but I was not successful. Can anyone give some help?

Comment: I'm a bit confused the first equation is for worldsheet coordinate while the second one is for coordinates of target space($X^{\mu}$)

Comment: @aitfel I have edited the question for better understanding

Comment: Can we move to a chat room to discuss this problem? I want to think about this problem but it will be useless for this comment section

Comment: @aitfel  Sure, i've created a chat room called "Static gauge in other backgrounds*